How do I account for replicates at the same sites when looking for spatial autocorrelation?
I am trying to examine the effect of spatial patterning/autocorrelation on a response variable at a number of sites distributed unevenly across a landscape (probably using Moran's I) but I'm unsure how to account for the fact that each of these sites has multiple replicates of data collection.
I don't think that the additional samples in each site can reasonably be considered statistically independent from variables at the same site in other years, and the longest time series from the dataset are also probably just a bit too short to analyze the data in terms of synchrony as opposed to spatial variation. In addition, some sites don't appear in every year of data collection and "average" values would likely do a poor job of describing these sites. I also don't think I can assume that the relationship among sites is the same in every year.
In short, I think I could conduct a valid statistical test of the relationship between distance and similarity among sites in each individual year, but I can't think of a way to put those years together into a more meaningful value. Does anyone have any advice on what I can do here?
